# Makefile - Set multiple variables on a single stage

Tags: variable, make, gnu, gnu-make

I have this Makefile where I'm having some troubles on simply set some variables:

```
my_stage:   
    echo "FULL_NAME=$(FULL_NAME)"
    echo "MY_NAME=$(MY_NAME)"

    $(eval SOME_NAME=$(shell sh -c "echo ${FULL_NAME} | cut -d"-" -f 2"))
    echo "SOME_NAME=$(SOME_NAME)"

    $(eval NAME_ONLY=$(shell sh -c "echo ${SOME_NAME}-only))
    echo "NAME_ONLY=$(NAME_ONLY)"

    $(eval RIGHT_NAME=$(shell sh -c "echo ${SOME_NAME}-right))

    $(eval NAME_APPENDED=$(shell sh -c "echo ${RIGHT_NAME}.${MY_NAME}))
    echo "NAME_APPENDED=$(NAME_APPENDED)"
```

The pretended result is:

```
FULL_NAME=Shop-with-me
MY_NAME=Mariana
SOME_NAME=with
NAME_ONLY=with-only
NAME_APPENDED=with-right.Mariana
```

However, the current result is:

```
FULL_NAME=Shop-with-me
MY_NAME=Mariana
SOME_NAME=with
NAME_ONLY=
NAME_APPENDED=
```

Can someone help me figuring out what is happening? What I'm doing wrong?

I already tried this too (but without success):

```
my_stage:   
    echo "FULL_NAME=$(FULL_NAME)"
    echo "MY_NAME=$(MY_NAME)"

    $(eval SOME_NAME=$(shell sh -c "echo ${FULL_NAME} | cut -d"-" -f 2"))
    echo "SOME_NAME=$(SOME_NAME)"

    NAME_ONLY = ${SOME_NAME}-only
    echo "NAME_ONLY=$(NAME_ONLY)"

    RIGHT_NAME = ${SOME_NAME}-right

    NAME_APPENDED = ${RIGHT_NAME}.${MY_NAME}
    echo "NAME_APPENDED=$(NAME_APPENDED)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use curly braces, like `${FOO}`, in your command, you refer to a a *shell* variable, as defined in the shell invoking `make`.

When you use parens, like `$(fOO)`, in your command, you refer to the make's variable.

Since you only set make's variables, obviously references to shell variables of the same name would result in empty values.

So `$(eval NAME_ONLY=$(shell sh -c "echo $(SOME_NAME)-only))` should work.

Simple `$(eval NAME_ONLY = $(SOME_NAME)-only)` should work in a rule. You don't need to invoke shell for that.

You can also consider using make's [text functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html), like `subst`.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps .ONESHELL will do what intended.

since gnu make launches a new process for each recipe line by default, the variable settings are not propagated to the recipe below.
.ONESHELL tries to runs all recipes of that target in a single shell invocation

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#One-Shell
.ONESHELL: